# при запуске pytest получаю "no tests ran"

Tags: python, selenium, test-automation, pytest

Есть проблема, при запуске pytest получаю "no tests ran" хотя assert прописан

```
class Registration:
    def open_site(self):
        driver.get('https://stellarburgers.nomoreparties.site/')
        WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,".//button[@class = 'button_button__33qZ0 button_button_type_primary__1O7Bx button_button_size_large__G21Vg']")))
        time.sleep(3)
        assert 'stellarburgers' in driver.current_url
```

а хочу получить статистику по прохождению тестов

Comment: Имена тестирующих классов обязаны начинаться на `Test`, а функции — на `test_` https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в синтаксисе
Если писать автотесты через классы, то нужно название класса начинать с TEST, а название функции с test_ иначе не заработает
то есть правильная версия выглядит так

```
class TestRegistration:
    def test_open_site(self):
        driver.get('https://stellarburgers.nomoreparties.site/')
        WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,".//button[@class = 'button_button__33qZ0 button_button_type_primary__1O7Bx button_button_size_large__G21Vg']")))
        time.sleep(3)
        assert 'stellarburgers' in driver.current_url
```